# AWS GLUE: Rename field name inside struct using Pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

The schema mentioned here is a part of my original schema, after using the Unnest transform in AWS Glue.

```
profile.details.indices.index: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- profile.details.indices.index.val.indexname: string
|    |    |-- profile.details.indices.index.val.indexsymbol: string
```

My requirement is to change the name of the two fields inside the struct ("profile.details.indices.index.val.indexname" and "profile.details.indices.index.val.indexname") to **indexname** and **indexsymbol** respectively using **pyspark**.

RenameField transform in the Glue did not work for the fields inside the struct, it yields same schema. After some research I found that I have to create a UDF to rename the fields inside struct, as I am new to Pyspark can anyone show me how to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I was able to find the solution for my question with the help of this blog : https://medium.com/@lvhuyen/working-with-spark-dataframe-having-a-complex-schema-a3bce8c3f44. Posting the answer here incase if someone has the same query.

I have created a new schema for the particular column by changing the field names and casted the schema for the column in the data frame

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    ArrayType, LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType)

struct_schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("indexname", StringType()),
    StructField("indexsymbol", StringType()),
]))

df_renamed = df.withColumn("profile.details.indices.index", col("`profile.details.indices.index`").cast(struct_schema))
```

Now the dataframe schema looks like this

```
|-- profile.details.indices.index: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- indexname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- indexsymbol: string (nullable = true)
```

There are also other solutions, but since my original schema had more than 100 other fields I found this solution to be helpful to change the particular nested column and retain the old schema